# Set a JavaScript ondblclick event to a class inside tinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Some words in my tinyMCE textarea editor are in a span tag with a specific class called "myclass". For instance, the word *Hello* that is visible in the tinyMCE textarea editor is in the source code with the following HTML code:

```
<span class="myclass" id="hello">Hello</span>
```

I try to launch a function on double click on the word *Hello*.

The usual jQuery code does not work for words inside the tinyMCE editor:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myclass').dblclick(function() {
        alert('class found');
    });
});
```

The function does not fire when I double click on the word *Hello* that is in the editor.

How can I bind the function to the tinyMCE editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TinyMCE uses an `iframe` element, so you cannot use `$('.myclass')` on your "main" scope in order to get elements inside that iframe (The content of the iframe is a different scope).
Instead - you need to run `$('.myclass').dblclick` in the scope of that iframe.

To do so you can use the `setup` callback and the `editor.on("init"` event that TinyMCE gives you:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector:'textarea',
    setup: function(editor) {
          editor.on("init", function(){
              editor.$('p').on('dblclick', function() {
                  alert('double clicked');
              });
          });
    }
});
```

Live demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d3yLttdb/).

> Note that `editor.$` is **not** a `jQuery` object, so you cannot do everything you are used to with jQuery, however it's pretty close.